# FFMPEG -f segment and FFPROBE keyframes are different

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I have a online video editor. And i want fast strip and concat mp4 files. For this i use code like this:

For get keyframes:

```
exe_ffprobe("-select_streams v -skip_frame nokey -show_frames -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time,pict_type $input_file");
```

Sample Result:

```
array (
  0 => '0.083417',
  1 => '2.085419',
  2 => '4.170838',
...
  12 => '24.149149',
  13 => '26.234568',
  14 => '27.569236',       < Why ffmpeg missed this keyframe?
  15 => '29.654655',
...
  230 => '466.966967',
  231 => '469.052386',
  232 => '471.137804',
  233 => '473.223223',
  234 => '475.308642',
  235 => '477.394061',
  236 => '479.479479',
)
...
```

For split video:

```
exe_ffmpeg("-y -i $input_file -c copy -map 0 -segment_list segments.csv -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 path/to/%d.mp4");
```

Sample result:

```
0.mp4,0.000000
1.mp4,2.085419
2.mp4,4.170838
...
12.mp4,24.149149
13.mp4,26.234568
14.mp4,29.654655
15.mp4,31.740073
...
230.mp4,475.308642
231.mp4,477.394061
232.mp4,479.479479
end
```

But count of keyframes from ffprobe, and count splitted videos are different.

So how i can segment or get keyframes correctly, to match the count

Also, keyframes and segments.csv are differently too, but more of keyframes has correct timestamps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `-segment_time` is not set, it defaults to 2 seconds and `27.569236` is less than 2 seconds away from `26.234568`, so the segment muxer will not start a segment at that KF.

Set `-segment_time 0.001` to make sure a segment is spawned for each KF, since ffmpeg will only cut at the next keyframe unless `-break_non_keyframes 1` is also set.

Comment: Thank you, it's work. Why the first frame is different?

Comment: The first segment starts from the beginning.